# Unable to view images from ipfs.blockfrost.dev

Tags: security, blockfrost, ipfs

I am unable to view images on ipfs.blockfrost.dev on my Mac. However, I can view them on my iPhone. I have tried Brave, Chrome, and Safari browsers.

Here is the error message I get when I click 'advance' in the security warning:

ipfs.blockfrost.dev normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Brave tried to connect to ipfs.blockfrost.dev this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials.

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved internally by Blockfrost support.

The end user had configuration problem with his operating system when all the `.dev` domains were redirected to a different website.